# What is the C# equivalent of the Oracle PL/SQL COALESCE function?

Tags: c#, oracle, coalesce

Is there a one statement or one line way to accomplish something like this, where the string s is declared AND assigned the first non-null value in the expression?

```
//pseudo-codeish
string s = Coalesce(string1, string2, string3);
```

or, more generally,

```
object obj = Coalesce(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...objx);
```

Answer (score 14):

As Darren Kopp said.

Your statement

```
object obj = Coalesce(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...objx);
```

Can be written like this:

```
object obj = obj1 ?? obj2 ?? obj3 ?? ... objx;
```

to put it in other words:

```
var a = b ?? c;
```

is equivalent to

```
var a = b != null ? b : c;
```

Answer (score 2):

the **??** operator.

```
string a = nullstring ?? "empty!";
```